# What's this red bubble on my Steam client?

Tags: steam, macos

My Steam client suddenly started jumping in my application dock (macOS) and now it looks like this:

[image: steam]

I don't have any new comments/messages/gifts/items/comments.

I can't see even if there's a number in the bubble or what.

Any ideas what this is?

Comment: Try right clicking on it and seeing if there is another window open. It could be for something like an update.

Comment: It's a notification indicator, so Steam probably wants you to do something.

Comment: Have you recently blocked a player? I've had issues in the past where I get notifications about unread messages from users I've ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a client update notification.

The update window got completely buried.

---

I ended up finding this thread [Steam: What does the OSX Steam dock red badge icon mean?](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/2/371918937274531107/)

where OP wrote:

> sometimes this badge indicates a steam client update.

So I tried clicking Steam --> Check for updates and then the update window popped up again.